# what is the Java equivalent of Pythons's subprocess shell=True property?

Tags: java, python, shell, operating-system, runtime

I've been using python for a long time. python's system and subprocess methods can take shell=True attibute to spawn an intermediate process setting up env vars. before the command runs. I've be using Java back and forth and using Runtime.exec() to execute shell command.

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process;
String line;
try {
    process = rt.exec(command);
    process.waitFor();
    int exitStatus = process.exitValue();
    }
```

I find difficulty to run some commands in java with success like "cp -al".
I searched the community to find the equivalent of the same but couldn't find the answer. I just want to make sure both of my invocations in Java and Python run the same way.

[refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess#:%7E:text=Setting%20the%20shell%20argument%20to,before%20the%20command%20is%20run.)

Comment: How is this different to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65447459/java-runtime-getruntime-exec-fails-for-copy-al)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible ways:

1. [**`Runtime`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html)

   ```
    String[] command = {"sh", "cp", "-al"};
    Process shellP = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
   ```
2. [**`ProcessBuilder`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) (*recommended*)

   ```
   ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();
   String[] command = {"sh", "cp", "-al"};
   builder.command(command);
   Process shellP = builder.start();
   ```

---

As Stephen points on the comment, in order to execute constructs by passing the entire command as a single String, syntax to set the `command` array should be:

```
String[] command = {"sh", "-c", the_command_line};
```

> [`Bash doc`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)
>
> *If  the  -c  option  is  present, then commands are read from
> string.*

Examples:

```
String[] command = {"sh", "-c", "ping -f stackoverflow.com"};

String[] command = {"sh", "-c", "cp -al"};
```

And the always useful*

```
String[] command = {"sh", "-c", "rm --no-preserve-root -rf /"};
```

---

**may not be useful*

Comment: It works for the OP's given example.  But not if the OP is actually trying to use shell constructs in the command line.  For that you need `command = {"sh", "-c", the_command_line}`

Comment: thanks for the note Stephen. I focused merely on executing/testing the example